# after running ng serve I'm getting error "an unhandled exception occurred Cannot find module '../dotjs/validate' "

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

**An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '../dotjs/validate'

**[this is my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE5yW.png)

```html
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
        "@angular/common": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/pwa": "^0.801.1",
        "@angular/router": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/service-worker": "~8.1.0",
        "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "1.0.6",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.34",
        "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.1.1",
        "@types/stompjs": "^2.3.4",
        "angular-text-input-autocomplete": "^0.3.0",
        "angular7-csv": "^0.2.12",
        "autolinker": "^3.14.1",
        "d3": "^5.15.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "keyboardevent-key-polyfill": "^1.1.0",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "net": "^1.0.2",
        "ngx-csv": "^0.3.2",
        "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.1.10",
        "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.2",
        "ngx-linky": "^2.2.0",
        "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
        "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
        "ngx-tour-core": "^4.1.1",
        "ngx-tour-md-menu": "^4.1.1",
        "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
        "puppeteer": "^5.2.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "rxjs-take-while-inclusive": "^2.1.1",
        "save": "^2.4.0",
        "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
        "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
        "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "twitter-text": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^13.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.8.3",
        "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^6.3.15",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "prettier": "2.1.1",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.3",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5"
    }
```

Previously i was getting following error :
"Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package."
I tried npm install command
also npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
and npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
Now Im facing above error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to uninstall the incriminated package and then run

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

and

`npm install --save-dev dotjs`

Comment: If the answer is works, please mark as correct. Thanks

Comment: Hey, previously same commands didnt worked but somehow worked this time ):
thanks!